# shuffle Numpy Array and pandas dataframe in unison

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe of shape (18837349,2000) and a 3D Numpy Array of shape (18837349,6,601). I want to shuffle the rows of my dataframe and the first dimension of my Numpy Array in unison. I know how to shuffle a dataframe:

```
df_shuffle = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I don't know how to do it together with a 3D Numpy Array. Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle an index and use them for both objects

```
ix = np.arange(18837349)
np.random.shuffle(ix)
df_shuffle, array_shuffle = your_df.iloc[ix].reset_index(drop=True), your_array[ix]
```

Comment: Note that it should be `ix = np.arange(len(range(18837349)))`.